# Creating Line between two other lines using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I work with ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

I want to create one polyline between two other existing lines and the new line must go through exactly the middle of the two existing ones. Something similar to the following drawing, except that the lines are not straight. Line 1 and 2 are in reality bathymetric curves.

_____________________________________  Existing Line 1

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Line that I need create

_____________________________________  Existing Line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option about what you are requesting:

cartography tools -> generalization -> Collapse Dual Line to Centerline

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/collapse-dual-lines-to-centerline.htm